# Python Embeddable zip file for Linux

Tags: linux, python-3.7

I have a Windows embeddable zip file that I use in Windows, I am trying to use it for linux but simply copy pasting it to linux doesn't work as the linux environment expects a different type of file extension.

I also don't see any embeddable distributions for python for linux on their website.

My question is, is it even possible to convert my windows embeddable zip file to a linux embeddable zip file? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly this won't work the reason being Windows embeddable zip is compiled upon the Windows Operating system.

What you can do is install Python on Linux using commands like

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Then you can run your python app/script as you do on the Windows Platform.

Alternatively, to solve such issues there's a containerization technology like Docker. Hope this helps.